# Looping over worksheets and applying filter

Tags: excel, vba

When I loop over worksheets and apply a filter it only adds the recipients (column B) from the first matching sheet, not the subsequent sheets.

```
Public Sub someFunction()

Dim recipients As String
Dim recipient As Range
Dim worksheet As worksheet

For Each worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case worksheet.Name
        Case "ABC Group", "DEF Group"
            ' DO NOTHING
        Case Else
            Worksheets(Worksheet.Name).Activate
            colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("a column name", ActiveSheet.Rows(5), 0)
            Rows(5).AutoFilter Field:=colNum - 1, Criteria1:="=some string*"
            With ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") - Or ActiveSheet
                For Each recipient In .Range("B6:B" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                    recipients = recipients + recipient + ";"
                Next recipient
            End With
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

The filter is however correctly applied to all matching sheets, and in the GUI the code finishes on the final sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a worksheet variable, so use it! No need for activating sheets when the sheet is explicitly defined.

You should change to worksheet variable to **not** match key VBA words/objects. I have changed it to `ws` since your naming method was too close to pre-defined VBA objects

Also, you build a string with the `&` operator, not `+`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub someFunction()

Dim mystring As String
Dim recipient As Range
Dim colNum As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "ABC Group", "DEF Group"
            ' DO NOTHING
        Case Else
            colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("a column name", ws.Rows(5), 0)
            ws.Rows(5).AutoFilter Field:=colNum - 1, Criteria1:="=some string*"

                For Each recipient In ws.Range("B6:B" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                    mystring = mystring & recipient & ";"
                Next recipient

    End Select
Next ws

mystring = Left(mystring, Len(mystring) - 1) '<-- Remove last instance of ";"

End Sub
```

Comment: I was copying the recipient value from the watch window in VBA IDE - it wasn't copying the full length of the string which was part of the confusion. Have also added edits as suggested. Thanks.